# Best way to implement frequent calls to taxing Python scripts

Tags: php, python, mysql, cron

I'm working on a bit of python code that uses mechanize to grab data from another website. Because of the complexity of the website the code takes 10-30 seconds to complete. It has to work its way through a couple pages and such.

I plan on having this piece of code being called fairly frequently. I'm wondering the best way to implement something like this without causing a huge server load. Since I'm fairly new to python I'm not sure how the language works.

If the code is in the middle of processing one request and another user calls the code, can two instances of the code run at once? Is there a better way to implement something like this?

I want to design it in a way that it can complete the hefty tasks without being too taxing on the server.

Comment: Describe what the script has to do, for each invocation.

Comment: 1. Load a site
2. Grab frame from site, load the frame on it's own
3. Set a form value, submit (updates the form with new options)
4. Submit again, it's a weird form (actually searches for results)
5. Submit again (Do I want to display more than 250 results)

Step 5 probably takes the longest because it seems to take a while to query 250+ results

Comment: Which parts of the process are invariant?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. I'm always loading the same pages, but the load length differs and the search value differs. Think of it as I'm trying to find the cost of an item a store with different departments. Step 3 specifies which department. Step 4 says any item over $20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My data grabbing scripts all use caching to minimize load on the server.  Be sure to use HTTP tools such as, "If-Modified-Since", "If-None-Match", and "Accept-Encoding: gzip".

Also consider using the *multiprocessing* module so that you can run requests in parallel.

Here is an excerpt from my downloader script:

```
def urlretrieve(url, filename, cache, lock=threading.Lock()):
    'Read contents of an open url, use etags and decompress if needed'    

    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    with lock:
        if ('etag ' + url) in cache:
            request.add_header('If-None-Match', cache['etag ' + url])
        if ('date ' + url) in cache:
            request.add_header('If-Modified-Since', cache['date ' + url])

    try:
        u = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        return Response(e.code, e.msg, False, False)
    content = u.read()
    u.close()

    compressed = u.info().getheader('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip'
    if compressed:
        content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(content), mode='rb').read()

    written = writefile(filename, content) 

    with lock:
        etag = u.info().getheader('Etag')
        if etag:
            cache['etag ' + url] = etag
        timestamp = u.info().getheader('Date')
        if timestamp:
            cache['date ' + url] = timestamp

    return Response(u.code, u.msg, compressed, written)
```

The cache is an instance of *shelve*, a persistent dictionary.

Calls to the downloader are parallelized with imap_unordered() on a multiprocessing *Pool* instance.

Comment: See the troublesome issue is the page isn't actually reloading (I believe) so "If-Modified-Since" doesn't help much. The page gets repopulated via javascript. It's so annoying.

Comment: If the servers aren't taking advantage of HTTP caching features, then minimizing server load is their problem, not yours.  That said, many sites that use Javascript to populate data will have terms-of-service that prohibit automated screen scraping.  In other words, if they haven't made it easy for you to get the data, then they likely don't want you to have it.

Comment: Yea it's an organization that setup a purchased system that happened to be difficult. I'm guessing the system was just really easy for everyone to use. I've personally talked with an IT person in the organization and they said it would be great if I made the app but they don't have any APIs in place to support it. The organization is huge and I don't think they're going to take the time to implement an API just for one person.


Oh and my concern wasn't about minimizing server load on their side, I don't want to overload my server with long running pieces of code that are frequently being run.

Answer (score 0):

You can run more than one python process at a time. As for causing excessive load on the server that can only be alleviated by making sure either you only have one instance running at any given time or some other number of processes, say two. To accomplish this you can look at using a lock file or some kind of system flag, mutex ect...

But, the best way to limit excessive use is to limit the number of tasks running concurrently.

Comment: One method I thought of using was to have users request a php file, which would set a value in a text file (lets say 1 for search, 0 to do nothing). I would then have a cron job run every minute which would trigger the python code which check the text file to see if it should run. Seems very convoluted though. I also felt like it would be taxing anyway to run a 30sec piece of code every minute.

Comment: SOmething like that could work fine, but it could get into a odd situation where the file is being written to and the process may get the wrong value, this can be worked around, but if you were to go this way keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is "you can run as many instances of your program you want, as long as they don't share critical ressources (like a database)".

In real-world, you often need to use the ["multiprocessing module"](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing) and to properly design your application to handle concurrency and avoid corrupted states or deadlocks.

By the way, design of multiprocesses app's is beyond the scope of a simple question on StackOverflow...

Comment: Yea I figured it might be beyond the scope of a simple answer. I'm looking for some links to good documentation and practices on such things. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it depend on you actual skills in programming and algorithmic. To learn algorithmic, I think good-old tools like pens, paper and books are the betters, as they naturally helps to keep your mind on theory.

For programming, example provided by the documentation is a good start.